# The representation of truncation protocol in SecureML

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, prime-field

The secure multiparty computation framework SecureML [1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7958569&casa_token=x2YGwHpBZGkAAAAA:c0dPgwW5NJ47uAikrno31UoMhvwINk4Y15f9Kg0b4QMO_rRm4K9dqQ4qD_3moAcXMLCYRIvlM6tpGg) has proposed a truncation protocol for decimal arithmetic in the integer field.

As mentioned in this paper,

> In field $\mathbb{Z}_{2^l}$, $x\in [0,2^{l_x}] \cup [2^l-2^{l_x}, 2^l)$, ...

Why is this representation employed? How can we interpret it?

Answer (score 0):

Since we need to support truncation after multiply operators, some extra bits should be preserved. Thus, the fixed point presentation of one number should be:

sign bit | extra bits(=fraction bits) | integer bits | fraction bits.

Here, lx = integer bits + fraction bits, l = sign bit + extra bits + integer bits + fraction bits.

However, we need to ensure that the probability of error is small enough so that we can set the ring size l bigger than sign bit + extra bits + integer bits + fraction bits.

More details can be found in the paper "Bicoptor: Two-round Secure Three-party Non-linear Computation".

Comment: Dear friend, we have $\LaTeX$/MathJax instaled!